# map loading at wrong offset at second time 

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, dialog

I have made a test page where you can check that whats the exact problem.

on first click its shows perfect map but when you close popup once and again click on `gmap` then popup opens but `gmap` shows one fourth.

[this is link of test page](http://e-hotelspro.com/gmap.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `Init()` each time the user clicks on the `gmap` link. This function creates a google map each time.

I see two possible solutions:

1. Only create the map the first time the user opens the dialog. When the user closes the dialog, jQuery actually hides the dialog div. The map still stays there, so there is no need to create a new map when you re-show the dialog. (declare `var map = null;` globally and test if `map` equals `null` before creating a new map each time the user clicks the `gmap` element.
2. Cleanup the map div when the dialog closes.

**Cleanup on dialog close**

Try this code to clean the `map` element on dialog close:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('document').ready(function () {
       $("#popup_container").dialog({
           autoshow: false,
           modal: true,
           border: 10,
           width: 500,
           height: 340,
           close: function(event, ui) {
              $('#map').html('');
           }
       });

       $('#gmap').click(function () {
           Init(); // initialize the map
           $("#popup_container").dialog("open");
       });
   });
</script>
```

**Also note that you need to pass the arguments to the `dialog()` method as a single object.**

Comment: how can i clean up the map on dialog close event

Comment: Add this option to the `dialog` initializer: `close: function(event, ui) { $('#map').html(''); }` to empty the map element on dialog close. Don't know if this will work though. The best bet might be to only create the map once. When you re-open the dialog for the second time, it will still be there. Because closing the dialog actually only hides the dialog div.

Comment: i am trying similar thing right now .. let you know very soon if this work for me thanks !

Comment: I have just use these three steps and its works for me sir . use $("#popup_container").dialog({ autoOpen: false }); instead of display:none, second thing open the dialog box using $('#popup_container').dialog('open'); and third is move the init() function after open method call and now its works . you can check there

Comment: Glad it works. But you should set the other options like modal, border, width, height, etc in the first initial call to `dialog()`. And pass all options as a single object instead of multiple objects (like you see in my answer). It's not clean to first open the dialog and then setting options like width & height.